# Parsing query into variable not working laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I've **query** like this

```
$sql_tampil = DB::connection('pgsql2')->select("SELECT sum(nilai) FROM laporan WHERE bulan='01' AND tahun='2011' AND (audited='0') AND");
$sql_tampil2 = DB::connection('pgsql2')->select("SELECT sum(nilai) FROM laporan WHERE bulan='03' AND tahun='2014' AND (audited='0') AND");
```

After **AND** is pass by another $variable

```
$sql_kas_setara = DB::connection('pgsql2')->select("$sql_tampil grupid='11'")->get();
```

and show it into **views**

```
return view('laporan.posisikeuangan_laporan')->with(['sql_kas_setara' => $sql_kas_setara]);
```

but laravel query doesnt read `AND grupid='11'`

this is the **error**

> SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at end of input
>   LINE 1: ...oran WHERE bulan='01' AND tahun='2011' AND (audited='0')
>   AND ^ (SQL: SELECT sum(nilai) FROM laporan WHERE bulan='01' AND
>   tahun='2011' AND (audited='0') AND)

How do I return the query after **AND** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DB::connection('pgsql2')->select("...")` will execute your query which is malformed because oft the `AND` at the and. There ist no `->get()` for raw statements. But you can just save your query in a string:

```
$sql_tampil = "SELECT sum(nilai) FROM laporan WHERE bulan='01' AND tahun='2011' AND (audited='0') AND";

$sql_kas_setara = DB::connection('pgsql2')->select("$sql_tampil grupid='11'");
```